# Facet counts on parent fields and child fileds in parent-child relationship?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search. I working on a search solution.Search solution is for hobby collectibles website. I prepared the parent-child relationship to make a effective search. Structure is give below :

**Parent structure** (type - collectibles) - This is collection of cards which are unique cards.

```
{ '_id':'ASFD45','title':'2012 topps #12 Micheal jordan','price':1.2,'sports':['baseball','football'],'players':['Micheal Jordan'] }
```

**Child structure** -- (type-marketplace)

```
"_index" : "bc_collectibles",
"_type" : "marketplace",
"_id" : "AVTljBJCdviQCMX-RSCw",
"_score" : 1.0,
"_routing" : "ASFD45",
"_parent" : "ASFD45",
"_source" : {
    "inventory_id" : 12217418,
    "owner_id" : 672,
    "item_id" : 1884176,
    "marketplace_category_id" : 120,
    "condition_id" : 6100,
    "power_dealer" : 0,
    "storefront_rating" : 4.87,
    "allow_offers" : 0,
    "highlight" : 0,
    "storefront_highlight" : 0,
    "on_sale" : 0,
    "price" : 0.5,
    "quantity" : 0,
    "item_and_source_crc" : "11884176",
    "use_stock_photo" : 1,
    "sku" : "",
    "storefront_type_id" : 6,
    "result_type" : 59,
    "created" : 1018364640,
    "updated" : 1443416400
}
```

**My Query :**
I want to make a search where user will search with card name and all card owner from marketplace will be display in results and in facet I need to aggregation on sports, player from parent and `marketplace_category_id`, `result_type` from child documents.

Please help me and give me idea how I will be able to complete this task.
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you might expect the response to look like given a mocked request?

Comment: Response : result":{"records":8595325,""applied_filters":Term":[{"key":"term","value":"1974+Topps+%233+Don+Hansen","title":"1974 Topps #3 Don Hansen"}]},
"available_filters":{"Sports":['key'=>'baseball','value'=>600],Players":['key'=>'Micheal Jordon','value'=>500]},"Marketplace_category_id":['key'=>'1200','value'=>500]},"power_dealer":['key'=>'Bufgva','value'=>900]},
"rows":[{"beckett_id":12217418,"owner_id":672,"item_id":1884176,"marketplace_category_id":120,"condition_id":6100}}